# Python sql loop

Tags: python, loops

This code runs fine in a python notebook in the current format. In the code I am inserting the start and end date of the month in various places. I would like to build the logic in an automated way, so that I can run this for a number of months by defining the start data and end date which will create a number of tables.

```
%sql

create table t_2020-01-31 as  
select mth,
      count(*) as customers
from (
select user_id,
cast('2020-01-31' as date) as mth,
case when a.user_id=b.user_id then 0 else 1 end new,
cast(max(orderdate) as date) as orderdate_l
from aaa  a left join (select user_id
                       from aaa
                       where orderdt <= '2020-01-01'
                       ) b
        on a.user_id=b.user_id
where orderdt <= '2020-01-31'
group by 1,2,3
)

group by 1,2
```

Comment: As you can see in the code... where? there's only text

Comment: '2020-01-31' is the end date of jan 2020 and '2020-01-01' is the start date of jan2020. I can run the code again for feb 2020 by inserting '2020-02-28' and  '2020-02-01' but I dont want to do this for every month

Comment: Can you tell us more about where you're having difficulty? The database api you're using probably has a (documented) mechanism for passing parameters into queries. Maybe show us the code you have so far and explain how you've tried to solve this?

Comment: I use the code above and the code runs fine. I could just run the code multiple time by inserting the start date and end date for each month, from 2020-01-01 to 2020-12-01 but would like to write the code in a more efficient way by using a loop